# Do Azure DevOps user stories have a retention period?

Tags: period, user-stories, retention

I'm trying to audit work that was done this year and have found that stories from back in January-March are missing. I'm able to see some of the releases for the later part of that period (Feb-March), but no stories. I've searched all of ADO for all of the story numbers from the releases we performed during this time and they are completely missing.

So, that leads me to my question. Do user stories have a retention period? Will they be removed after a certain period of time? If so, where is that setting?

Comment: Did you mean to ask this on a company-specific Stack Overflow-like forum?

Comment: I was searching for support through Microsoft's site and the options were to go through an MS support plan or be redirected to Stack Overflow, so I chose SO.

Comment: Your edit makes more sense. Thank you.